# AngularJs: ngAnimate issue when routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ng-animate

**Update:** I can avoid by using setTimeOut function.
I put all config or init function in timeline Controller into setTimeOut function, but I dont really understand the ngAnimate

---

I have an Angular Application with some templates, and I use **ngRoute** to switch.
In a template and its controller, I create a map View with **google maps API**.
If I didn't inject **ngAnimate** to my app modules, everythings is ok.

But, if I injected **ngAnimate** to my app modules:

- If I use  to routing to this template, googleMapsAPI **does not work**, but no any Error throw in Console.
- I use sly.js to make timeline slider. And its init function not work too.
- If I refresh this template (F5), everything work normally.

My code like that:

My module file

```
var app = angular.module("application", ['application.services','ngAnimate','ngRoute','angular-loading-bar']);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/home', {
    templateUrl: base_url + "/index.php" + "/app/home",
    controller: "homeCtrl"
})
.when('/search', {
    templateUrl: base_url + "/index.php" + "/app/search",
    controller: "searchCtrl"
})
.when('/lesson/:lessonId', {
    templateUrl: base_url + "/index.php" + "/app/lesson",
    controller: "lessonCtrl"
})
.when('/groups/:groupId', {
    templateUrl: base_url + "/index.php" + "/app/groups"
})
.when('/timeline/:region', {
    templateUrl: base_url + "/index.php" + "/app/timeline",
    controller: "timelineCtrl"
})
.when('/timeline', { redirectTo: '/timeline/vn' })
.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
```

My Timeline Controller File

```
angular.module("application")
.controller('timelineCtrl', function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location, mapTimelineProcess, renderProcess, BASE_URL) 
{   

if($routeParams.region != 'vn' && $routeParams.region != 'wo') {
    $location.path('/');
}

$scope.events = [];
$scope.timeline = [];
var swFlag = 0;

$scope.region = $routeParams.region; // Choose VN or WO Timeline

$scope.curCentury = 0;
$scope.curYear = 0;

// Create map
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    mapTimelineProcess.initialMap();
})

// Congigure Slider
mapTimelineProcess.slidersInit();
... ...
```

In my View

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/vendor/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/modernizr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/script.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDzmqGgteQuwwllDX9QmG60gVjP6laXDBc">
</script>                       

<!-- AngularJS Setting -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/vendor/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/vendor/angular-animate.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/css/loading-bar.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/loading-bar.js"></script>

<script>
    var base_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/modules/services/app-services.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/modules/services/app-timeline-services.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/modules/application.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/modules/controllers/app-home-ctrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/modules/controllers/app-timeline-ctrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/modules/filters/app-filters.js"></script>
... ...

<div class="main-page"> 
    <div id="main-content" ng-view>

    </div> <!-- Main Content -->
</div> <!-- Main Page -->
```

Who can give me an advise, thanks you

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Can you describe in more details how you fix this by posting an answer. I'll upvote you.